# ls -I myExecutable is listing the rest of the dir files instead of showing info about the file

Tags: files, permissions, ls, chmod

Working on Raspian, after compiling using make, I do a `ls -I myFile` in order to see the permissions of the file and if it is marked as executable as it should and instead of getting something like that `-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 24204 Dec 26 09:49 myFile` I get what I would get if I ran a simple ls but without the `myFile` listed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is found in `man ls`,

```
   -I, --ignore=PATTERN
          do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN
```

In other words, you asked `ls` to ignore the file, to only list the other files.

If you want a long list, you should use the option `-l` lower case 'ell'.

```
   -l     use a long listing format
```

So try

```
ls -l myFile
```

Answer (score 2):

You add your file in ignore list with key `-I` (letter i caps). You should replace it with `-l` (letter L small)

```
ls -l myFile
```

Comment: You were both correct and I can't tell which one was the first to answer.

Comment: @ChristosK. This answer was 24 seconds earlier. If you mouse over the text above their name that gives the relative time of their answer, it will tell you the exact time. Personally, however, I would accept sudodus's answer because it explained your error in more detail.

Comment: @ChrisosK: Hovering over the "answered ... ago" text should give you the UTC timestamp for the answer.  Alternatively, you can choose to display the answers in "oldest" order (the tab above the answers) though this doesn't seem to be functioning correctly for these answers.  In this case Romeo Ninov answered 24 seconds earlier.  I think sudodus' answer is better though.